# How to define prefix that can turn numeric?

Tags: functions, packages, variable-definitions, variable

I put these prefix in my `init.m` file. First I `Unprotect` all these symbols, set values and then
`Protect` again so they cannot be changed.  However, I got errors when I use `ClearAll["Global'*"]` as these variables are protected and not allowed to clear. I can leave these variables unprotected but this is unwanted as they can be changed probably by accident. 
 How would you solve this? Or do you have a better idea to do this? 
The unit package doesn't help as they don't give me numerical values.

```
Unprotect[Yocto, Zepto, Atto, Femto, Pico, Nano, Micro, Milli, Centi, 
  Deci, Deka, Hecto, Kilo, Mega, Giga, Tera, Peta, Exa, Zetta, Yatta, 
  mySIprefix];
Remove[Yocto, Zepto, Atto, Femto, Pico, Nano, Micro, Milli, Kilo, 
  Mega, Giga, Tera, Peta, Exa, Zetta, Yatta];
mySIprefix = {"Yocto", "Zepto", "Atto", "Femto", "Pico", "Nano", 
   "Micro", "Milli", "Centi", "Deci", "Deka", "Hecto", "Kilo", "Mega",
    "Giga", "Tera", "Peta", "Exa", "Zetta", "Yatta"};
Thread[{Yocto, Zepto, Atto, Femto, Pico, Nano, Micro, Milli, Centi, 
    Deci, Deka, Hecto, Kilo, Mega, Giga, Tera, Peta, Exa, Zetta, 
    Yatta} = 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \({\(-24\), \(-21\), \(-18\), \(-15\), \(-12\), \(-9\), \(-6\), \(-3\), \(-2\), \(-1\), 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24}\)]\)];
Protect[Yocto, Zepto, Atto, Femto, Pico, Nano, Micro, Milli, Centi, 
  Deci, Deka, Hecto, Kilo, Mega, Giga, Tera, Peta, Exa, Zetta, Yatta, 
  mySIprefix];
```

Somehow I cannot reprocedure the error now. 
However, I got this error when I run my init.m file.
(I have other packagage loaded before this as well)
I think that the error is because of the unit package I loaded and haven't removed. The last messages are a bit weird to me though.
I just removed the unit package plus my other package and the error disappeared.

[image]

Comment: Start the file with ```BeginPackage["Prefixes`"]``` and end the file with `EndPackage[]`. That way  the symbols will live in their own context and won't interfere with the Global context.

Comment: ClearAll should ignore symbols that are Protected. Are you sure that's where you're getting errors? Can you provide the actual errors you're seeing. FWIW, I can't generate any errors when trying to follow your instructions.

Comment: SjoerdSmit thanks
@lericr somehow I cannot reprocedure it now. However, if I run it in the init.m I got this error. 
I'll update it in my post.

Comment: Ah. It looks like you had loaded the Units` context, and so you're getting a name clash because those SI prefix symbols are also in the Units` context. I would either follow Sjoerd's suggestion and create your own context, or just use the built in functionality around Quantity expressions. E.g. you can do `Quantity[1, "Femto" "Meter"]`, and then you can do whatever arithmetic or conversions that you want.

Comment: @lericr I just removed the unit package and the error disappeared. I want to input something like `3 Nano` and it can be evaluated to `3*10^-9`. I can type `3*10^-9` directly but it is slower than just type `3 Nano`.

Comment: There are several other options. You could use `*^` (e.g. `3*^-9` evaluates to 3*10^-9). You could define InputAliases (easiest to do through the options inspector). You could define functions instead of constants. None of these are necessarily better--just thoguht you might be interested in alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

With v13 there is no problem with the built-in units . What version are you using?

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

prefix = {"Yocto", "Zepto", "Atto", "Femto", "Pico", "Nano", "Micro", "Milli",
    "Centi", "Deci", "", "Deka", "Hecto", "Kilo", "Mega", "Giga", "Tera", 
   "Peta", "Exa", "Zetta", "Yatta"};

quantitiesShort = Quantity[1, # <> "meter"] & /@ prefix
```

[image]

```
quantitiesLong = UnitConvert@quantitiesShort
```

[image]

```
quantitiesLong // N // ScientificForm
```

[image]

```
quantities = QuantityMagnitude@quantitiesLong
```

[image]

```
quantities // N // ScientificForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I used V12 but I updated to V13 today. Yours work but I should have added my motivation better. I have to input something like  `3*10^-9`, `2*10^-12` but this is a bit long and slow to type. So I want to make some prefix like  `Nano`, `Pico` so I just need to type simply as  `3 Nano`, `2 Pico`.

Comment: ‘3*^-9’ and ‘2*^-12’  are just as short and don’t damage built—in for their intended use